Access parent object from child?
I have some problems understanding the following code.
I have a class inside a class (it was given that way and we should use it like this) and I want to use the Fitter class to change the vocabulary attribute of the Tokenizer class.
The problem is I don't understand how I can access the Parent object.
Here is the code of my classes:
class Tokenizer(TokenizerABC):
    def __init__(
        self,
        vocabulary,
        pre_tokenizer
    ):
        self._vocabulary = vocabulary
        self._pre_tokenizer = pre_tokenizer

    class Fitter(TokenizerABC.Fitter["Tokenizer"]):
        """A builder-style object for fitting a tokenizer to a corpus."""
        def __init__(self, lowercase=False, limit=None):
            ...


        def fit(self, corpus: list[str]) -> TokenizerABC:
            """Fit a tokenizer to the given corpus.

            Args:
                corpus (list[str]): The corpus to fit the tokenizer to.

            Returns:
                Parent (Generic[TokenizerABC]): The fitted tokenizer.
            """
            # some code

            vocabulary = # some code

            return ...

    @classmethod
    def fitter(cls) -> Fitter["Tokenizer"]:
        """Create a new Fitter object for this tokenizer.

        Returns:
            Fitter[Self]: The Fitter object for this tokenizer.
        """
        return ...

And in the test code the objects are initialized with:
abcd = ["a a a b", "c c c d d"]
tokenizer = Tokenizer.fitter().fit(abcd)

I use Python 3.12.

Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Sorry i made an error while copying my code. Its just here in the page

I don't understand what exactly you want. Generally, objects in the enclosed class are not connected to objects of the enclosing class, e. g. you can call Tokenizer.Fitter(...) to create a fitter without a tokenizer. You can only add a parameter to the Fitter constructor which expects a Tokenizer object to explicitly create a connection.

A class inside a class isn't a "parent-child" relationship. There is no "parent" object. Indeed, in Python, nesting class definitions doesn't do anything except put the nested class in the namespace of the outer class. Which just makes things harder generally speaking. That being said, it isn't clear to me what you are trying to do exactly. You really need to explain that

i think i misunderstood the fitter() function. It has @classmethod in it so i should use it to create the object and dont have to try to access an already existing object.

@Herakles the fitter method seems completely pointless. This entire design is not something you should consider reasonable. It would never pass a sane code review

presumably, the fitter method would simply do return Tokenizer.Fitter(), but then you could just use Tokenizer.Fitter() instead of Tokenizer.fitter(). Totally silly and overengineered. Someone is writing Java in Python and it shows.

There is no ordinary way to do that. The Fitter class would have to be given an explicit reference to its parent when it is created (i.e., there should be a parameter in its __init__ function which would receive its 'parent', then it could store that as an attribute and get back to its parent.
Otherwise, there are some mechanisms in Python which could allow the "Fitter" instance associated with a Tokenizer instance to automatically know which Tokenizer instance it is - but, you have to be able to change the Tokenizer class code - and give us a better example. Is a Fitter instance attached to a Tokenizer instance, or to the Tokenizer class ? It is confuse in your example - and the way to use descriptors in order to add the contextual information you need will change.
Even if you can't change the Tokenizer source code itself, if it is Python code, it can be "monkey patched" so that its associated "fitter" becomes a descriptor, instead of a plain attribute, and then your goal could be achieved.
Unfortunatelly, without a minimal working example, with correct indentation, and the creation of the fitter attribute in the Tokenizer class, I cannot help with a code example.
